# How do I add a paragraph above an element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a todo list as my first js project but I can't figure out how to put the new elements on top of each other. Here's my code

When I press the button it adds the elements all on the same line.

```js
function buttonFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById("textbox");
  document.getElementById('blank').insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", x.value)
}
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text" value=''>
<button id="button" onclick="buttonFunction()">Add task</button>
<p id='blank'> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements are probably on the same line due to positioning, so insert the following into a `<style></style>`.

```css
#textbox, #blank {
    display: block;
}
```

This allows for them to be like this:

**`<ELEMENT>`**
**`<ELEMENT>`**

instead of **`<ELEMENT>`** **`<ELEMENT>`**

Comment: In the CSS file? Sorry but I am very new to this

Comment: Yes in a CSS file or a style tag

Comment: lmk, if you need any more help :)

Comment: I used an ordered list and got it to work